# Manipulating DOM with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

The code below is supposed to add a `p` element to my document, add text to this element, and change the font color of the element to `red`.

This is for a class. I have been working on this for two hours but am stumped.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>

      <h1 id='demo'>
        THE TITLE OF YOUR WEBPAGE
      </h1>
      <div id="container">
        <div class="content">
          This is the glorious text-content!
        </div>
      </div>


    </body>
    <script>
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = 'Hey, I'm red.';
    p.style.color = 'red';
    div.content.appendChild('p');

    </script>

</html>
```

The code doesn't produce the desired results. 
Can any of you help me understand what I am missing?

Comment: Well the first thing you might notice in the syntax highlighting is that you've included a single quote *within* a single-quote string. You should do `"Hey I'm red."`, using double quotes instead. Also, `div` is not defined. Your code has no idea what `div` is. You'll need to  tell it that you want an element on the page by doing something like `document.getElementById("container")`.

Comment: Its look you forget getting div with id content dom reference. Plase try `document.getElementById('content').appendChild(p)

Answer (score 1):

Here `'Hey, I'm red.';` , you need to escape the quote before `'m` by using back slash or else you can put inside double quotes.

Beside `div.content.appendChild('p');` here div need to a be a target which you can get bus using the `document.getElementById` & inside `appendChild` you need to pass `p` as a variable

```js
const p = document.createElement('p');
p.textContent = 'Hey, I\'m red.';
p.style.color = 'red';
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(p);
```

```html
<h1 id='demo'>
  THE TITLE OF YOUR WEBPAGE
</h1>
<div id="container">
  <div class="content">
    This is the glorious text-content!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have few issues in your code:

1. The *textContent* you are using (`'Hey, I'm red.'`) is not valid.

   You can use double quotes to surround the whole string so that you can use single quotes inside the string like `"Hey, I'm red."`.

   **OR:** you can escape the inner quotes with back slash (`\`) like `'Hey, I\'m red.'`

   **OR:** You can use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) wrapping the string with back tick like:

   ```
   `Hey, I'm red.`
   ```
2. You have to use `document.getElementById()` to target the element.
3. You also have to remove the quotes around the variable *p* in  `appendChild('p')`, other wise the quotes treat that as *string* not *variable*:

```js
const p = document.createElement('p');
p.textContent = "Hey, I'm red.";
p.style.color = 'red';
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(p);
```

```html
<h1 id='demo'>
  THE TITLE OF YOUR WEBPAGE
</h1>
<div id="container">
  <div class="content">
    This is the glorious text-content!
  </div>
</div>
```